# Sencha touch 2: Making changes to framework source

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm attempting to make changes to Sencha Touch's javascript source to increase scrolling performance.

What's the standard practice for this?

I've tried changing the source in my `workspace/touch/resources/src` or straight up changing the `sencha-touch-all-debug.js` file. How do I issue a build to take these changes? I can't figure out where the build process is currently pulling the source from as my changes do not make it into the build at all.

Thanks,
Jonny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways you can attempt this, but ultimately you will create an override and include this file in your application.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.override.SomeClass', {
    override : 'Ext.some.Class',

    someMethod : function() {}
});
```

That's the recommended way. Some additional resources for you:

- http://moduscreate.com/writing-ext-js-overrides/
- http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cmd_packages/cmd_creating_packages.html#Overrides
- http://www.sencha.com/blog/creating-theme-specific-overrides-in-ext-js
- http://senchatouchdev.com/wordpress/tag/sencha-touch-override/

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I can actually scroll with decent performance now!